# I get Method not found: 'FSharp.Data.HttpResponse FSharp.Data.Http.Request...' when attempting to call Http.Request from Powershell module

Tags: powershell, f#, f#-data

I am using VS 2019 and installed the FSharp.Data package using nuget.  From Visual Studio all works fine but when I create a powershell module using code similar to the following:

```
type FetchData() =

    member private s.url = "<some url>" 

    member public s.GetRawResponseObject() =
        let foo = s.url
        let resp = Http.Request(foo)
        resp

    member public s.GetString() =
        let resp = s.GetRawResponseObject() 
        let body = resp.Body
        let str =
            match body with
            | Text x -> x
            | Binary x -> ""
        str



[<Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Data")>]
type GetRawData() =
    inherit PSCmdlet()

    override x.EndProcessing() =
        let fetch = new FetchData()
        let data = fetch.GetString()
        x.WriteObject data
```

I get an error stating that "Get-Data : Method not found: 'FSharp.Data.HttpResponse FSharp.Data.Http.Request(…"

My unit tests pass within VS2019 but when I import the module and call the cmdlet I get the error.

I added the following to my app.config but it did not help.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.8.0.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Is this a .NET Framework or .NET Core application? Are you using PowerShell (core) or Windows PowerShell?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 and Windows PowerShell.

Comment: I guess my question is why are you even doing this? Couldn't you just code this in powershell?